# Adaptive crf value in ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I use a crf value of 19 wich works, but some times the bit rate gets too high. Basically I want to know how to make ffmpeg try to keep the quality level at 19 but when the bit rate gets too high, lower the crf value, but also have a max crf value.

Comment: If the answer is not what you want to hear PM me :)

Comment: It droped it to a point (21) but then wouldn't go any lower. Maybe it's a problem with libx264?

Comment: I found the problem, I was useing -qp insted of -crf. Thanks

Comment: ah :D glad I could help even though it was just by supplying an example with the correct options :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264):

> **CRF with maximum bit rate**
>
> You can also also use a crf with a maximum bit rate by specifying both crf *and* maxrate settings, like

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -maxrate 400k -bufsize 1835k output.mp4
```

> This will effectively "target" crf 20, but if the output exceeds 400kb/s, it will degrade to something less than crf 20 in that case.